# Frenet serret formulas vector analysis question

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, frenet-frame

If unit tangent vector $\bar{t}$ and binormal vector $\bar{b}$ make angle $\theta, \phi$ with a constant unit vector $\hat{a}$. So prove that $$\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\phi}\cdot\frac{d\theta}{d\phi}=-\frac{\kappa}{\tau}$$

I am not sure how to approach the problem. But applying the frenet-serret formulae $$\frac{dt}{ds}=-\frac{\kappa}{\tau}\frac{d}{ds} \\ \frac{dt}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{ds}=-\frac{\kappa}{\tau}\frac{db}{d\phi}\frac{d\phi}{ds}$$

Now if I can show $dt/d\theta= \sin\theta;db/d\phi= \sin\phi$ it would be proved. However I am unable to see how or why that would be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
  \cos \theta = \frac{\langle \bar t, \hat a\rangle}{\|\bar t\| \|\hat a\|} = \langle \bar t, \hat a\rangle
$$
and similarly $\cos \phi = \langle \bar b, \hat a\rangle$.
Then
$$
 \begin{align*}
 \frac{\sin \theta\, d\theta}{\sin \phi\, d\phi} 
                         &= \frac{d(\cos \theta)}{d(\cos \phi)} \\
                         &= \frac{d( \langle \bar t, \hat a \rangle)}{d(\langle \bar b, \hat a \rangle)} \\
                         &= \frac{\langle d(\bar t), \hat a \rangle}{\langle d(\bar b), \hat a \rangle} \\
&=
 \frac{\langle \bar t', \hat a \rangle}{\langle \bar b', \hat a \rangle}.       
 \end{align*}
$$
To find the answer, apply the Frenet-Serret formulas for $\bar t$ and $\bar b$.

Comment: And at the last step you can add $=\dfrac{\langle\bar t',\hat a\rangle}{\langle\bar b',\hat a\rangle}$. It looks like somewhere we'd better assume that $\hat a$ is not in the rectifying ($\bar t\bar b$-) plane.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Ok, thanks for the constructive comment.